# number of ways to tile a $n\times n$ grid with $k<n^2$ $1\times 1$ tiles?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, tiling

So, there are alot of questions about tiling in this forum but I could not find this exact question.

I am trying to find out the number of possible "tile configurations" in an $n\times n$ grid where the tiles are $1\times 1$ and there are k less than or equal to $n^2$ of them. I have link down below with the "tile configurations" for a $2\times 2$ grid.

I don't know, but I feel like I am missing some simple way of approaching the problem. I've been trying to frame it in the context of the combination formula, but I feel like my intuition is lacking... Anyway, if someone could give me a hint that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where does 17 come from?

Comment: You missed one for $k = 2$ (all black ones on top), and you haven't counted $k = 0$ (the answer becomes much nicer if you do).

Comment: Hmm, for some reason the picture doesnt show ll configurations. There's supposed to be one more for k=1, k=2, and k=3, to left of the picture...

Comment: Is this not "$k$ choices for the first tile, $k$ choices for the second tile, ..., $k$ choices for the $n \times n^\text{th}$ tile, so $k^{n^2}$ tilings"?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

For any integer $k \le n^2$ there are $\binom{n^2}{k}$ ways to pick $k$ tiles from the $n \times n$ grid. If you want to count all but $k \in \{0,n^2\}$, you will receive
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\binom{n^2}{k} = 2^{n^2} - \binom{n^2}{0} - \binom{n^2}{n^2} = 2^{n^2} - 2
$$
In your drawing, you missed "2 on top". Summing up the numbers for $k \in \{1,2,3\}$ you receive
$$
4 + 6 + 4 = 14 = 16 - 2 = 2^{2^2} - 2
$$